# Invalid type when creating a map of <string, list<innerclassobject>>

Tags: apex, map, wrapper-class, inner-class

> Invalid type: EcPerformanceRecordList

I want to create a Map of userid and list of sObject records, then loop 
    through this map so that I can count how many apps have been submitted per 
    user.

This is an example of the EcPerformanceRecordList:     e.g

```
UserID  Total  EC(Yes)     Date
user1   12      4          06/12/2019
user1   13      13         06/13/2019
user2   35      24         06/18/2019
user3   23      31         07/02/2019    
user1   17       2          07/10/2019
user3   12       3          07/10/2019

Map<String, List<EcPerformanceRecordList>> ecusermap = new  Map<String, 
List<EcPerformanceRecordList>> ecusermap();



ecusermap.put(user1, <{user1 12 4 06/12/2019}, {user1 13 13 06/13/2019},{user1 17 2 07/10/2019} )

ecusermap.put(user2, <{ user2 35 24 06/18/2019}, {user1 13 13 06/13/2019},{user1 17 2 07/10/2019} ) and so on.
```

then for each user, i want to loop through the list and calculate the totals.

Here's snippet of my code for reference.

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    public list<MyWrapper> wrapper {get;set;}
    public integer appTotal {get;set;} 
    public integer mtdappTotal {get;set;} 
    public integer previousmonthappTotal {get;set;} 
    public integer idlplusmtdTotal {get;set;}
    public integer idlpluspreviousmonthTotal {get;set;}
    public integer caTotal {get;set;}
    public integer ecmtdTotal {get;set;}
    public integer ecpreviousmonthTotal {get;set;}
    public integer ecEligibleYesMTDTotal {get;set;}
    public integer ecEligibleYesPreviosMonthTotal {get;set;}
    public Map<String,list<EcPerformanceRecordList>> ecusermap {get;set;}


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public void getdeserialize() {

        try{
            string jsonresponse = 'SOME STRING'


            wrapper = (list<MyWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(jsonresponse, list<MyWrapper>.class);


            // call the method that aggregates the MonthToDate app count, and PreviousMonth app count per user 
            getTotalECBookedByUser(wrapper);



        } catch (Exception e){
            system.debug('Error---->' +  e.getLineNumber() + e.getMessage());

        }
    }



// This method calclates the total EC Booked current month and previous month by each user 
public integer getTotalECBookedByUser(list<MyWrapper> wrapper) {

    // create a map of submitUserID and ECSubmittedRecordList 
    Map<String,list<EcPerformanceRecordList>> ecusermap = new Map<String,list<EcPerformanceRecordList>>();  
    for(MyWrapper jw: wrapper){

        jw.ecpreviousmonthTotal=0;
        jw.ecmtdTotal = 0;   

        for (MyWrapper.EcPerformanceRecordList ec : jw.ecPerformanceRecordList) {

            if(ecperuserMap.containsKey(ec.submitUserID)){

                 ecperuserMap.get(ec.submitUserID).add(ec);

            }else {

                ecperuserMap.put(ec.submitUserID,ec);
            }

        }
    }

    //TODO: 
    // for each key, loop through the values in ecperuserMap and count the total apps submitted by each user this month and previous month 



    return ecpreviousmonthTotal;
    return ecmtdTotal;

}



}




------------------------Wrapper Class ------------------


public class MyWrapper {
@AuraEnabled    
public List<CaPerformanceRecordList> caPerformanceRecordList{get;set;}
public List<EcPerformanceRecordList> ecPerformanceRecordList{get;set;}
public Map<String,List<EcPerformanceRecordList>> ecPerUser {get;set;}
public integer appTotal{get;set;}
public integer mtdappTotal {get;set;} 
public integer previousmonthappTotal {get;set;} 
public integer idlplusmtdTotal {get;set;}
public integer idlpluspreviousmonthTotal {get;set;}
public integer caTotal {get;set;}
public integer ecmtdTotal {get;set;}
public integer ecpreviousmonthTotal {get;set;}
public integer ecEligibleYesMTDTotal {get;set;}
public integer ecEligibleYesPreviosMonthTotal {get;set;}





public class EcPerformanceRecordList {
    public String DealerID{get;set;}
    public String submitUserID{get;set;}
    public String bookedDate{get;set;}
    public String ecEligible{get;set;}
    public Integer caBookedCount{get;set;}
    public Integer ecBookedCount{get;set;}


}


public class CaPerformanceRecordList {
    public String DealerID{get;set;}
    public String dealerName{get;set;}
    public String reportingPeriod{get;set;}
    public String financeSourceIntegrationTypeCode{get;set;}
    public String idlPlus{get;set;}
    public String creditApplicationSourceCode{get;set;}
    public Integer submissionCount{get;set;}
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EcPerformanceRecordList` is an inner class of `MyWrapper`. Outside the scope of `MyWrapper`, including inside the class `MyController`, you must refer to it with its fully-qualified name `MyWrapper.EcPerformanceRecordList`:

```
public Map<String,list<MyWrapper.EcPerformanceRecordList>> ecusermap {get;set;}
```

and so forth.